# Lazy loading dynamic proxy POCOs n+1 select

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Consider the following entity model and function:

```
public class Order
{
  public int OrderId {get; set;}
  public int StatusId {get; set;}

  public virtual Status OrderStatus {get; set;}
}

public class Status
{
  public int StatusId {get; set;}
  public String Name { get; set;}
}

public void ShowOrders()
{
  //load all status entities.
  //Will EF check for these in object cache first when I access order.Status for
  //the first time?
  //Or perhaps even auto include them in materialised orders?
  context.Status.Load(); 

  //enumerate orders without explicit status include
  foreach(Order o in context.Orders.ToList())
  {
    //Get Status navigation property for each order
    //Will database be hit?
    Console.WriteLine("Order: {0:N}, Status: {1}", o.OrderId, o.OrderStatus.Name);
  }
}
```

I know I can explicitly do:

```
context.Orders.Include(o=>o.OrderStatus).ToList();
```

to include Status when querying for orders to prevent n+1 selects. And I know that if I access `Order.OrderStatus` navigation property that `DbReferenceEntry.IsLoaded` is checked and a cached Status object retrieved if possible before database is hit.

What I'm wondering is if `DbReferenceEntry.IsLoaded` and `DbReferenceEntry.CurrentValue` are populated when the parent entity is materialised (even if `.Include()` is not called) if the reference entity is in the object cache already?

So in this example above when accessing `Order.OrderStatus` **for the first time** does a database query get executed even though all Status are in object cache because of the `Status.Load()` call prior to enumerating orders?

Answer (score 0):

EF will check the object cache first whenever a navigation property is accessed, so if all the Status entities are already loaded accessing Order.OrderStatus shouldn't issue a database query.
DbReferenceEntry will be populated during materialisation if the reference is already in the object cache.

If you are concerned about the number of queries being issued consider turning off Lazy Loading so in cases where an automatic query would be issued you'll get a null instead.

For more performance guidance see this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx

Comment: Thanks, would you mind clarifying. I've updated question. I'm not specifically asking about `.Load()` and I know that `DbRefrenceEntry.IsLoaded` is checked when accessing nav props.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test the following statements (by watching when and which SQL queries are actually run in a profiler), they are only guesses:

> does a database query get executed even though all Status are in
>   object cache because of the Status.Load() call prior to enumerating
>   orders?

If a database query is **not** executed I'm pretty sure that the reason is **not** that *specifically* `context.Status.Load()` is called. This is only a snapshot of the `Status` database table at the time when `context.Status.Load()` is executed. At the point where you enumerate the orders EF can't be sure that the `Status` table hasn't change in the meantime and additional `Status` rows have been inserted. So, to avoid a wrong data representation EF *must* run a new query - unless EF has other means to recognize if a query is required or not.

And there are other means, in this case because an `Order` entity has only a *reference* to `Status`, not a `Status` collection. When the `Order`s get loaded - by enumerating `context.Orders.ToList()` - EF will always load the foreign key to `OrderStatus`, no matter if you use `Include` for the `Status` or not. It would even be the case if you hadn't exposed the FK `StatusId` as property in your model. At the moment when an `Order` is materialized, relationship fixup will run and check if a `Status` entity whose primary key has the same value as the FK loaded together with the `Order` already exists in the object context. If yes, the `Order.OrderStatus` property will immediately be set to that `Status` entity - and I guess, EF will mark the navigation property as `IsLoaded`. For a reference there can be only one matching entity and it wouldn't make sense to run a query if that entity is already attached to the context and assigned to the navigation property.

So, I would say: No query is run if the right `Status` object is attached to the context. It doesn't matter if by running `context.Status.Load()` or by loading only this specific `Status`, running any other query that would load this `Status` or by manually attaching the `Status` to the context (`context.Status.Attach(...)`).

This behaviour must change in my opinion if `Order.OrderStatus` would be a *collection*. When an `Order` gets loaded now there is no FK to `Status`. Instead the `Status` had an FK to `Order`. If you load `Status` entities first - by `context.Status.Load` or any other query - the Order-FK would be loaded with the `Status` objects. If you later load an `Order` relationship fixup would run again, this time the other way around: EF looks if there are any `Status` objects in the context that have an FK refering to the loaded `Order`. If yes, it will add the `Status` to the `Order.OrderStatus` collection. But this time - big guess - it can't mark the navigation property (the `Order.OrderStatus` collection) as `IsLoaded` because it can't be sure that really **all** `Status` objects for this `Order` have been loaded previously or that a new `Status` for that `Order` hasn't been added to the database in the meantime.

So, I guess, if you access the `Order.OrderStatus` collection lazy loading will run to ensure that the potential "rest of `Status` objects" for that `Order` gets loaded as well. Then it will mark the collection as `IsLoaded`. It might not need to add any additional `Status` to the collection, but the query is necessary at least to check if the collection was complete or not.